# Two harmonic functions(in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$) are coincided in $\mathbb{S}^n$ then they`re same?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

There are two harmonic functions are defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and they are same on 
 $\mathbb{S}^n$.

I think, they are same on $\mathbb{B}^{n+1}$.

Because, $\mathbb{S}^n$ is boundary of $\mathbb{B}^{n+1}$ and elliptic maximum principle.

But my question is that they are same on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ ??

Comment: [FYR](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91436/unique-continuation-principle)